# How to restore firefox history, bookmarks, cache from installed directory of an other hard drive

Tags: firefox, browser, bookmarks, history, browser-cache

My old hard drive is faulty, OS wasn't booting, so installing the OS wasn't successful, so bought a new hard drive, installed new OS, installed firefox, now I want to restore all the bookmarks, history, cache, settings etc from firefox installed in old hard drive. The faulty drive is readable. I can access the installation folder of firefox of faulty harddrive. How to restore all of those?

Firefox version of both previous and current: 47.0.1

EDIT: Operating System: Windows 10

Comment: Take a look: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/restore-bookmarks-from-backup-or-move-them

Comment: Just copy the data from the old profile to the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which OS are you using?

You can pretty much restore EVERYTHING in your firefox settings, if you can get the files out of the old hard-drive.

In any case, the simplest option is to just copy the WHOLE mozilla/firefox directory to your new installation.

**On Linux** you can simply copy your old mozilla directory from your home folder `~/.mozilla` to your new home folder.

**On Windows**, I believe you need to copy two folders:
`<yourUserDirectory>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox`
`<yourUserDirectory>\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox`

Comment: Thanks, bookmarks and history restored, but the cache seems to be not restoring after copying/replacing the files in \Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox folder

Comment: Can you try also copying `AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox`?  This second folder seems to have offline cache database.